# Difference between P(A)+P(B) and P(A)+P(B) - P(A&B)

Tags: conditional-probability, inclusion-exclusion

COuld you please explain me the difference between

1. P(A) + P(B)
2. P(A) + P(B) - P(A & B)

I thought that:

1. meant "Probability that either A or B or both happen" so basically **at least one** event happening.
2. meant "Probability that **only one** of A or B happens but NOT both".

But this seems to be wrong because I am seeing problems that are solved in different ways, like assuming that 2) is the probability of at least one event happening, which is what I thought was 1).

Comment: When we simply sum $P(A)+P(B)$, we are counting *twice* the probability of $A\cap B$ occurring. So the probability that at least one event occurs is $$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B).$$
The probability that one and only one of them occurs is $$P(A\Delta B)=P(A\setminus B)+P(B\setminus A)=P(A\cup B)-P(A\cap B)=P(A)+P(B)-2P(A\cap B).$$

Comment: See [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#In_probability) (especially, the Venn diagrams there).

Comment: @nejimban are you saying that P(A) + P(B) is then NEVER correct because it would mean overcounting?

Comment: They are both equal if and only if $P(A\cap B)=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be easier to see what is going on if you split $P(A)$ and $P(B)$:

- $P(A)=P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap B^c)$
- $P(B)=P(A\cap B)+P(A^c\cap B)$

So

- Probability of at least one is $$P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap B^c) +P(A^c\cap B) \\= P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$$ subtracting once to avoid double counting the intersection
- Probability of exactly one is $$P(A\cap B^c) +P(A^c\cap B) \\= P(A)+P(B)-2P(A\cap B)$$ subtracting twice to avoid counting the intersection at all